# How to call CMake in a setuid program?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, setuid

I wanna call `CMake` from a `setuid` executable on *Linux*. The code for the callcmake.cpp is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setuid(geteuid());
    system("cmake ..");
}
```

and then I typed the following under account A

```
g++ callcmake.cpp -o callcmake
chmod 4755 callcmake
```

I tried to run this callcmake with another account B, cmake has the following output:

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:172 (CONFIGURE_FILE):
>     configure_file Problem configuring file
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)
>
> -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:177 (CONFIGURE_FILE):
>     configure_file Problem configuring file
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)

How can I run cmake with a setuid program?

Comment: Is the build directory where you run `callcmake` belonging to the good user (the one you setuid)? Please edit your question to give more details.

Comment: Yes it is, and the directory's ACL is set to 700. @BasileStarynkevitch